# Каждый раз при запросе ajax, создается новая сессия

Tags: php, javascript, сессия

При каждом `ajax` запросе на сервере создается новая сессия (в папке `storage/sessions/`)
Я пишу в сессию токен, потом вставляю его вот так
`<meta name="csrf" content="<?= $_getToken ?>">`
что бы можно было `js` вытянуть его и передать `ajax request`ом`

Вот так я вытягиваю и посылаю token

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('_token', document.querySelector('#csrf').content)

fetch('/cart/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        PHPSESSID: token
    },
    body: formData
})
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function (json) {
        console.log('parsed json', json)
    }).catch(function (ex) {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex)
    })
```

Класс [Session](https://gist.github.com/Insidexa/6a9eb456fc34ae40b9c3a956e7f17294)
Класс [FileSessionHandler](https://gist.github.com/Insidexa/7e296bc370fdb83267cbbedc3c2e1d61)

Comment: А если дописать `credentials: 'include'` в параметры fetch?

Comment: это сработало, огромное спасибо, можете предложить как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` немножко параноик и по умолчанию не передаёт куки от сайта, на который отправляется запрос (а идентификатор сессии хранится в куке `PHPSESSID`). За передачу кук и заголовков авторизации отвечает опция `credentials`, которая может иметь одно из следующих значений:

- `'omit'` (по умолчанию) — не передавать куки и заголовки авторизации;
- `'same-origin'` — передавать, только если домен, на который отправляется запрос, совпадает с доменом текущего сайта (точнее, origin; сложный случай, но текущего вопроса не касается, так что не буду его подробно описывать);
- `'include'` — передавать.

Собственно, в данном случае достаточно просто прописать `'include'`:

```
fetch('/cart/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: formData
})
```

P.S. `PHPSESSID` — не заголовок, а кука, не надо его в `headers` пихать, браузер сам передаст все нужные куки